# Trying to update an SQL database entry, receiving a SQL syntax error. How do I figure out what's going wrong here?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

Below is my code to connect to a simple server and update information etc.

```
package mysqltest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MySQLTest {
    static Connection con = null;
    static Statement stmt = null;
    static ResultSet result = null;

    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coffeeshop";
    static String user = "root";
    static String password = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {                 
            // SQL query string          
            //update specifics
            String push1 = "INSERT INTO Coffees"
                + "(CoffeeName, SupplierID, Price, Sales, Total)"
                + "values"
                + "('Colombian', 95, 5.95, 0, 0)";

            String push2 = "INSERT INTO Coffees"
                + "(CoffeeName, SupplierID, Price, Sales, Total)"
                + "values"
                + "('French Roast', 27, 6.95, 0, 0),"
                + "('Espresso', 104, 7.95, 0, 0),"
                + "('Colombian Decaf', 95, 16.45, 0, 0),"
                + "('French Roast Decaf', 27, 8.45, 0, 0)";

            String push3 = "UPDATE Coffees"
                + "SET SupplierId=12, Total=2"
                + "WHERE CoffeeName='Colombian'";


            String push4 = "DELETE FROM Coffees WHERE CoffeeName='Colombian'";
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Coffees";
            //clear everything first

            //push updates
            connect();
            pushUpdate(push1);
            //need to reconnect after update as update closes connection after updates.
            connect();
            queries(query); 
            pushUpdate(push2);
            connect();
            queries(query);
            pushUpdate(push3);
            connect();
            queries(query);
            pushUpdate(push4);
            connect();
            queries(query);
}
    public static boolean connect(){
        boolean connect;
        try{
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            connect = true;
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + ex.getMessage());
            connect = false;
        }
        return connect;
    }

    public static void pushUpdate(String push){
        try{
            stmt.executeUpdate(push);
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        try{
            con.close();
            stmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + ex.getMessage());   
        }   
    }

    public static void queries(String query){
        try{
            result = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.printf("%-10s%-35s%-12s  %-9s%-7s%-7s\n", 
                "CoffeeID", "CoffeeName", "SupplierID", "Price", "Sales", "Total");             

            while (result.next()) { // loop until the end of the results                 
                    int coffeeID = result.getInt("CoffeeID");
                    String coffeeName = result.getString("CoffeeName");
                    int supplierID = result.getInt("SupplierID");
                    double price = result.getDouble("Price");
                    int sales = result.getInt("Sales");
                    int total = result.getInt("Total");
                    System.out.printf("%8d  %-35s%10d  %7.2f  %7d%7d\n", coffeeID, coffeeName, supplierID, price, sales, total);
                }

        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Exception caught: " + ex.getMessage());
        }finally {
            try {
                if (result != null) {
                    result.close();
                }
            }catch (SQLException ex){
                System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I have a table already created and I update the table according to the "push". Push 1, 2, and 4 work fine, however 3 is throwing this error...

"SQLException caught: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '=12, Total=2WHERE CoffeeName='Colombian'' at line 1"

Ok, so basically I've tested push3 as it is written in my program, written into the cmd prompt and it works fine. Obviously without using the "+" symbol.

[cmd prompt snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2I21.jpg)

Comment: Looking at what you've posted above, there is no space between the Total=2 and the WHERE clause.  I'm not sure what "basically tested push3" means, but a quick cut-and-paste of that code into SQL should show you that it's invalid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spaces are important.  This:

```
"UPDATE Coffees"
+ "SET SupplierId=12, Total=2"
+ "WHERE CoffeeName='Colombian'"
```

Becomes this:

```
"UPDATE CoffeesSET SupplierId=12, Total=2WHERE CoffeeName='Colombian'"
```

`CoffeesSET` is invalid and `2WHERE` is invalid, resulting in the entire statement being unparseable.  Add spaces where you need them:

```
"UPDATE Coffees "
+ "SET SupplierId=12, Total=2 "
+ "WHERE CoffeeName='Colombian'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your string, it becomes obvious, that you have simply missing some whitespaces here. Your string becomes

> UPDATE CoffeesSET SupplierId=12, Total=2WHERE CoffeeName='Colombian'.